# How to reopen or reset WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, sessionid

I'm programming a Windows Forms Application with a `WebBrowser` control and I need to change `Session ID` on the web server. How can I do it? Is there any method to restart or reopen the browser?

Answer (score 2):

To clear session (such as HttpOnly cookies), you can use InternetSetOption() from wininet.dll.

```
private const int INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION = 42;

[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
```

and use this method whenever need to clear session.

```
InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
webBrowser1.Document.Window.Navigate(url);
```